# Java : A pipe used in a print statement in java?

Tags: java, pipe

What is it when a pipe is used in print statement in java? For example

```
System.out.println(6 | 3);
```

Output : 7

```
System.out.println(6 | 4);
```

Output : 6

Comment: It's the "Binary OR" operator?

Comment: see this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple

System.out.println(6 | 3);

Performing `"OR" operation` of two values using corresponding binary values.

```
6 - 0 1 1 0
3 - 0 0 1 1 (OR)
-------------
    0 1 1 1 (7)
-------------
```

System.out.println(6 | 4);

```
6 - 0 1 1 0
3 - 0 1 0 0 (OR)
-------------
    0 1 1 0 (6)
-------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          6 | 3  6 | 4
6 binary:  110    110
another:   101    100
bin or:    111    110
transform:  7      6
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a binary [bitwise or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operator, and it produces an `int`. We can inspect the values in binary and decimal with a small program like

```
int i = 6;
for (int j = 3; j < 5; j++) {
    System.out.printf("%d (%s) | %d (%s) = %d (%s)%n", i,
            Integer.toBinaryString(i), j, Integer.toBinaryString(j),
            (i | j), Integer.toBinaryString(i | j));
}
```

And the output is

```
6 (110) | 3 (11) = 7 (111)
6 (110) | 4 (100) = 6 (110)
```